# How to store the value in datagridview in to a collection class C#

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, datagridview

First, I import a csv file to the datagridview and changed it to the format that I want.

I'm able to filter out the data that i do not want by clicking a button, i get the data i want in the console by using console.writeline. (just for testing so  i can see what's actually happen). There are quite numbers of column that do not content the data i want for calculation, so i use `.contains()` and `.replace` to filter it out.

Now, i want to store the cell.value.toString()  which hold the value to an array but i have no idea how to implant array to it.

Here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace test2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {   
        OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();

        public int colC { get; private set; }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                List<string[]> rows = File.ReadLines(openFile.FileName).Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToList();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                List<string> headerNames = rows[0].ToList();

                foreach (var headers in rows[0])
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(headers);
                }
                foreach (var x in rows.Skip(1).OrderBy(r => r.First()))
                {
                    if (x[0] == "Lot ID")   //linq to check if 2 lists are have the same elements (perfect for strings)
                        continue;     //skip the row with repeated headers
                    if (x.All(val => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val))) //if all columns of the row are whitespace / empty, skip this row
                        continue;
                    dt.Rows.Add(x);
                }

                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
               // dataGridView1.Columns["Lot ID"].ReadOnly = true;    
                //dataGridView1.Columns[" Magazine ID"].ReadOnly = true;
                //dataGridView1.Columns["Frame ID"].ReadOnly = true;

            }
        }

        public void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFile.Filter = "CSV|*.csv";

        }

        public void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|Csv files (*.csv)|*.csv";
            sfd.FilterIndex = 2;


            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName, false);
                    {
                        string columnHeaderText = "";

                        int countColumn = dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1;

                        if (countColumn >= 0)
                        {
                            columnHeaderText = dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText;
                        }

                        for (int i = 1; i <= countColumn; i++)
                        {
                            columnHeaderText = columnHeaderText + ',' + dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText;
                        }


                        sw.WriteLine(columnHeaderText);

                        foreach (DataGridViewRow dataRowObject in dataGridView1.Rows)
                        {
                            if (!dataRowObject.IsNewRow)
                            {
                                string dataFromGrid = "";

                                dataFromGrid = dataRowObject.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                                for (int i = 1; i <= countColumn; i++)
                                {
                                    dataFromGrid = dataFromGrid + ',' + dataRowObject.Cells[i].Value.ToString();

                                }
                                sw.WriteLine(dataFromGrid);
                            }
                        }

                        sw.Flush();
                        sw.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exceptionObject)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exceptionObject.ToString());
                }
                }
            }

        public void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    //prevent error occur coz , only execute the not null line
                    if(cell.Value != null)
                    {
                        string cellV = cell.Value.ToString();

                        //do operations with cell, filter out the unnecessary data 
                        if (!cellV.Contains("="))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                       else if (cellV.Contains("P = "))
                        {
                            cellV = cellV.Replace("P = ", "");
                        }
                        else if (cellV.Contains("F = n/a"))
                        {
                            cellV =cellV.Replace("F = n/a", "0");

                        }
                        else if (cellV.Contains("F = "))
                        {
                            cellV = cellV.Replace("F = ", "");

                        }

                        Console.WriteLine(cellV + "\n");
                    }

                }
            }

        }

    }
    }
```

Please have a look in the last method and the Picture. 
[image]

Here is the output.
[image]

I skip all the data which is not related to calculation by using `continue`

How do i store the data that i filtered out in array???

Please do not hesitate to ask if you have any inquiry about the question.

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what your question is. It appears that whatever you are trying to do… you are making it far more complicated than it has to be. What is `button3_Click` event supposed to do? You may want to peruse… [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) …  AND [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am try to implant an array to cell value so that i can make some calculation. button3_click suppose to do the calculation but I not yet complete the function.

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something… I do not know what you mean by _“implant an array to cell value so that i can make some calculation”_... It looks to me like the button 3 event is trying (unsuccessfully) to parse the cells that contain the equal (=) character. The code you posted is not much help, the first one reads a csv file, seconds saves it, third is doing what appears to be an attempted parse for the strings that contain “=”. Without knowing what you want to achieve, an answer would be mostly speculation.

Comment: Sorry for unclear question. Actually, i try to store the output data in a collection class. As u can see, I already filter out all the unwanted data like "P" or "P =" because in calculation not needed those data. I use `console.writeline` to check whether i filter the right data or not. Can u understand so far??

Comment: As I commented, it appears you want to parse the strings that have an equal “= ” sign in the string. Example: in a cell that has a string value of “P = 10.65” you want to get only the `decimal` portion of the string, i.e… 10.65 and store it as a `decimal` so you can do some calculation with it.. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Exactly! That's what I m trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that this may help. First and more important, is that when you loop through a `DataGridView` that has a `DataSource`, it is better to do modifications/additions, etc… through the `DataSource` instead of the grid. In this example it will make no difference, however, the code below loops through the `DataSource` (the `DataTable`) and not the grid.

Below is a revised button 3 click that will convert the strings that contain equal “=” signs to `decimal` values. If the string that contains an equal “=” character and does not have a valid decimal number after the equal sign… zero (0) is returned. A helper method is used to take the string “P = XX.xx” and returns a valid `decimal` number or zero (0) if the number is invalid. Hope this makes sense.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  decimal decimalNumber = 0.0m;
  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++) {
      if (row.ItemArray[i] != null) {
        if (row.ItemArray[i].ToString().Contains("=")) {
          decimalNumber = GetDecimalFromEquation(row.ItemArray[i].ToString());
          textBox1.Text += decimalNumber.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        }
      }
    }
    textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
  }
}

private decimal GetDecimalFromEquation(string numberString) {
  decimal parsedValue = 0.0m;
  if (numberString.Contains("=")) {
    numberString = numberString.Replace(" ", "");
    string[] splitArray = numberString.Split('=');
    if (splitArray.Length >= 2) {
      decimal.TryParse(splitArray[1], out parsedValue);
    }
  }
  return parsedValue;
}
```

Possible cleaner version of the read csv method.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    List<string[]> rows = File.ReadLines(openFile.FileName).Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToList();
    List<string> headerNames = rows[0].ToList();
    foreach (var headers in rows[0]) {
      dt.Columns.Add(headers);
    }
    foreach (var x in rows.Skip(1).OrderBy(r => r.First())) {
      if ((!(x[0] == "Lot ID")) || (!(x.All(val => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val)))))
        dt.Rows.Add(x);
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
  }
}
```

Lastly, possible cleaner version of the write method. It uses the `DataTable` instead of the grid itself.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
  sfd.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|Csv files (*.csv)|*.csv";
  sfd.FilterIndex = 2;
  if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    try {
      using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName, false)) {
        string columnString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count - 1; i++) {
          columnString += dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
          if (i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 2)
            columnString += ",";
        }
        sw.WriteLine(columnString);
        string rowString = "";
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
          rowString = "";
          for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count - 1; i++) {
            rowString += dr.ItemArray[i].ToString();
            if (i < dt.Columns.Count - 2)
              rowString += ",";
          }
          sw.WriteLine(rowString);
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception exceptionObject) {
      MessageBox.Show(exceptionObject.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `List<string> values` and store the values in the string using 
`values.Add(cellV);`

You can then use `values.ToArray()` to get an array to the stored values.

Your function will look like this

```
public void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<string> values = new List<string>();
        // Create a new instance of the Form2 class
        // Form2 goForm2 = new Form2();

        // Show the settings form
        // goForm2.Show();

        //string checkP = "p = ";
       // string removePE = checkP.Replace("P = ", "").Replace("F = ", "");


        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                //prevent error occur coz , only execute the not null line
                if(cell.Value != null)
                {
                    string cellV = cell.Value.ToString();

                    //do operations with cell
                    if (!cellV.Contains("="))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                   else if (cellV.Contains("P = "))
                    {
                        cellV = cellV.Replace("P = ", "");
                    }
                    else if (cellV.Contains("F = n/a"))
                    {
                        cellV =cellV.Replace("F = n/a", "0");

                    }
                    else if (cellV.Contains("F = "))
                    {
                        cellV = cellV.Replace("F = ", "");

                    }
                    values.Add(cellV);
                    Console.WriteLine(cellV + "\n");
                }

            }
        }

    }
```